# Best way to display a list of information for an object such as a recipe in an Android App?

Tags: android, layout, design, interface, mobile-application

Currently, I have this:

[image: (What I currently have)]

However, it doesn't seem like a proper way to display it (*I censored two lines to hide the main idea of my application*).

What would be a proper way to display it?

Comment: The list contains information only and the list items are not clickable?

Comment: @AndreDickson exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have seen many apps grouping similar types of details and then segregating them in tabs, which are horizontally scroll able using gesture and click. It reduces scrolling and user can find the information he is looking for easily compared to traditional scrolling interfaces.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. The [Android list pattern](https://material.google.com/components/lists.html#lists-usage) isn't best suited for this.

> Lists are best suited to presenting a homogeneous data type or sets of data types, such as images and text. They are optimized for reading comprehension while differentiating either between similar data types, or qualities within a single data type.

My advice would be to group the content into a single display-text element and format the text as a list. Or, use a display-text element for each item and stack them vertically.

[image: Android example]

The above [example](https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-multi-line-text-field) shows input-text fields stacked vertically (and in one case horizantally) but the idea is the same for display-text fields.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can't find an example image but hopefully the updated description helps.

Comment: Hmm, maybe drawing it on MS Paint? I didn't really get the idea ;)

Comment: I was waiting for a response, didn't know you edited it. :P